# Cant create react app using npx create-react-app directly

Tags: reactjs

When I create react app, I should first run the command "npm install create-react-app" then "npx create-react-app name", otherwise it will throw error, but others only need the the second command, Why?

I tried downloading latest version of node js, npm and clearing my cache but it still throw error when i try to run

```
npx create-react-app name
```

and still need to run npm install create-react-app.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What's the error ?

Answer (score 1):

you should no longer need to install `create-react-app` globally. The recommended way to create a new React app is using the `npx`

If you have previously installed create-react-app globally, it might be conflicting with the latest versions. Try uninstalling it:  `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

You can clear the cache using: `npm cache verify`

and lastly, you can create the app using: `npx create-react-app@latest my-app`

Answer (score 0):

the create react app is deprecated. use

```
npm create vite
```